# Number of observations showing in x-axis legends

Tags: r, visualization

This Basic R code creates a boxplot. For some reason, the number of observations appear in the x-axis legends. There should be only A and B, not A50 and B50. Can you tell me what is the matter and how to fix this?

```
a <- df$A
b <- df$B

C <- list(a,b)

names(C) <- c(paste("A", length(a), sep = ""), paste("B", length(b), sep = ""))

par(mgp=c(3,2,0))

boxplot(C, col = "red", ylab="value")
```

[image]

Comment: names(C) <- c("A", "B")  should do it. You are creating new names for your columns with "A" and "lenght of A". I guess A is 50 rows, as well as B. YOu told R to rename A to A50 and B to B50

Comment: Thank you @pbraeutigm that was the reason and solution

Comment: Or simply `boxplot(df[c("A", "B")])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason as to why the number of observations is appearing on the x-axis is due to the use of the function `paste`. The function `paste` combines two parts, separated by space (" ").

1. A constant string `A`
2. Length of vector `A`

When you use paste this way, it takes a constant string `A` and appends it to the length of vector `a` resulting to something like `A5` if the length of vector `a` is 5. The same applies to `B`.

To fix the issue, you should specify the names of the vectors without appending the lengths of the vectors as follows;

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  B = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
)
a <- df$A
b <- df$B

C <- list(a, b)

# Specify the names as "A" and "B" directly
names(C) <- c("A", "B")

par(mgp = c(3, 2, 0))

boxplot(C, col = "red", ylab = "value")
```